# How to install Java 13 to Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, java, dpkg, jdk

I downloaded `jdk-13.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb` from oracle and installed using `dpkg`. However,

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

doesnt show `java13`. How do i get the `java -version` to `java13` now?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: You need `update-alternatives --install` first, before you can config alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's answered, I'll give you another answer in case you need Oracle/Sun Java (some applications may work only with it, not openjdk).

Download the generic Linux .tar jdk from Oracle, not .deb specific for Debian. Untar to a path, for example `/opt/SunJava`. (I kept Sun in the path, I had it like this before it was taken over by oracle).

in your profile add these lines:
`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/SunJava/`
`export JRE_HOME=/opt/SunJava/jre/`
`export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/SunJavaCurrent/bin/java 100`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/SunJavaCurrent/bin/javac 100`

`update-alternatives --display java`
`update-alternatives --display javac`

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`
`sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

That way you can have Oracle/Sun JDK available and able to choose between OpenJDK and OracleJDK. You can also use alternatives to have many different versions of java available. Or you can achieve this using softlinks, `ln -s`.

Comment: Awesome. Exporting path is awesome. However its long but good.

Comment: Please don’t continue speading the old stories about Oracle / OpenJDK incompatibility. Since version 11, [both are functionally identical](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later), according to Oracle themselves.

Comment: As you said, since version 11. Many enterprises are still developing on ver 1.8 or even 1.7. It's not easy for every developer to upgrade her applications on the newer platform. Personally I have seven Java versions (even one from IBM!) in total on my debian pc due to incompatibilites between production apps on the companies I run projects for.

Answer (score 3):

Install the OpenJDK 13 packages available [in Kali](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/openjdk-13):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jdk
```

OpenJDK 14 is also available:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
```

Since (from comments) you’re currently using Java 11, you should review the release notes and migration guides for the successive versions: [Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/), [Java 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/), [Java 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/).

Java 11 is [the current LTS](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html), it will be maintained for a number of years; releases 12 through 15 are non-LTS releases, so they are only maintained for six months.